# My basement toilet and shower will not drain after it rains

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I just had a bathroom put in my basement. It's been working fine but yesterday we had a lot of rain and now the toilet won't flush and the shower will not drain.

It is a septic system and the other toilets and sinks have no affect of the basement bathroom.  Every other sink, toilet and bathtub in the house drains just fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info: do  you have a septic system? a sewage ejector pump? Does flushing an upstairs toilet affect the basement toilet or shower?

Comment: It is a septic system and the other toilets and sinks have no affect of the basement bathroom.

Comment: Hello, again. It looks like you've created two accounts, [Scott](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/95451/scott)  and [srussels](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/95456/srussells). Please use the SE Contact page to request a merge of your two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If your basement has a back flow preventer when the water level is high the pressure in the line from a raised water level is probably the cause. I had this happen, built the bathroom in the summer, it worked great until several days of rain then no draining like you have. Whatever you do don't make the mistake I did and think the back flow valve was plugged , when I opened it up got all the brown trout from the line above. I ended up having to add a pump to the system if I remember correctly it was around 500$ for the tank& pump a small one but we never had any problems after that.